# MVC how to change dropdownlist item names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Been googling for a while, but I can't seem to get any closer.

I'm using MVC with an EF Database structure.

I want the dropdownlist items in the View to show up with different names than what they come up with.

Right now, the lambda query returns a list().
I want each item to get a string name depending on their current name.  Eventually, the selected field needs to be used in another lambda as the Byte that it was.

**Edit**

```
//view
<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
<p>
    @Html.DropDownList("vbType", (SelectList)ViewBag.Type, "" , new { onchange = "form.submit();" })

....

//controller
var typeLst = new List<byte>();
var typeQry = from t in db.model1
       orderby t.TYPE
       select t.TYPE;
typeLst.AddRange(typeQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.vbType = new SelectList(typeLst);

....
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `SelectListItem` to display in your dropdownlist.

Example:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YearStartedToPay,
       Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Today.Year - 60, 61).OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).Select(n => new SelectListItem() { Text = n.ToString(), Value = n.ToString(), Selected = false }).ToList<SelectListItem>(),....)
```

In this case, I'm creating an Enumerable, that will be your list returned from EF, ordering and selecting as a SelectListItem.

Comment: Thank you, Liam! It was my first time here, I don't know how to create that block code! Appreciate that!

Comment: Have a read though this [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: So in short, move most of the stuff I wanted to do in the Controller to the View?

Comment: In my opinion, I don't know what you want to do in the controller, but populate ddl source or other fields you can do directly in the view! The controller is more responsible for the model and some business rules.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make use of dropdownlist's Value property. Make your list a type of SelectListItem.

Assign Text= [Your Required Text] and Value = [Current Name]

Comment: Needs more details